# A basis for the 1-cycles of the Klein bottle (simplicial homology)

Tags: algebraic-topology

The context is integral simplicial homology. Consider the following triangulation of the Klein bottle: [image: klein]

I want to write down a basis for the $1$-cycles explicitly, without resorting to linear algebra (i.e., without writing down a huge matrix and reducing).
The chain complex looks like this: $$0 \to  Z^{18}  \to Z^{27} \to Z^{9} \to  0. $$Helpful facts: since the bottle is non-orientable, the second homology is trivial, i.e., there are no non-trivial $2$-cycles. This implies that all $18$ triangles that generate the $Z^{18}$ yield $18$ independent $1$-cycles through the boundary operator. Moreover, since the bottle is connected, the zeroth homology has rank $1$, which implies that the rank of $0$-boundaries is $8$, which in turn implies that the $1$-cycles have rank $27 - 8 = 19$. Therefore, our basis should consist of $19$ $1$-cycles, and we already have $18$ of them (the boundaries of the $18$ triangles). This means that any other $1$-cycle that is linearly independent with the $18$ triangle cycles, such as $ag + gd + da$, should complete the picture. But this doesn't feel right as I can't figure out a way to write down an arbitrary $1$-cycle that is not a triangle or a rectangle, such as $bc + cf + fi + ib$, in terms of these $19$. Am I missing something or is that really a basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without orientations, we cannot do the calculations, but you can move paths around by adding and subtracting triangles.  Each triangle gives a relation such as $ag=\pm gi\pm ai$ (depending on the orientations).  This is a replacement rule.

Your approach, while it does identify the fact that the 18 triangles are independent, fails to find the extra 1-cycle $ab+bc+ca$.  This is because the 18 triangles only can get $2(ab+bc+ca)$.  Over a field this would not be an issue, but $\mathbb{Z}$ does not have division by 2.  This might be why you could not find a way to represent $bc+cf+fi+ib$, since homologically it is a sum of $ab+bc+ca$ and $ag+gd+da$.

I am not sure you can actually do this calculation without something equivalent to a big matrix, unfortunately, since independence can be tricky to infer (being a statement about non-existence of a solution to a system of equations), and over $\mathbb{Z}$ even spanning can be tricky.

If what you want is an explicit description of a basis of 1-cycles, here is a computational trick from graph theory: (1) take any spanning tree of the graph (2) count the number of edges outside the spanning tree. Each edge corresponds to an independent cycle by attaching the unique shortest path through the tree between the two endpoints. Spanning implies there is such a path (otherwise you can add that edge to make the tree bigger). In your example, the complement of a spanning tree has 19 edges. These span the 1-cycles because an arbitrary 1-cycle will be cut up by the spanning tree, and anything completely inside the tree is not a cycle or 0.

Comment: Isn't the sum of all $18$ triangle $1$-cycles precisely $2(ab + bc + ca)$ (or the opposite, in the other orientation)? And since the boundary map $Z^{18} \to Z^{27}$ has trivial kernel, it must map the $18$ linearly independent triangles to $18$ linearly independent triangle $1$-cycles, no?

Comment: It seems I made a mistake with my orientations and logic and should have caught it.  They are indeed independent.  For calculating homology $ab+bc+ca$ is important since it is a generator for the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ component.  (By what reasoning do you know $ag+gd+da$ is independent of the triangles, by the way?)

Comment: Actually, thinking about it more, the triangles do *not* form 18 of the elements of the basis, since they miss the cycle $ab+bc+ca$.  This is the treacherousness of linear algebra over a ring: the failure of the dimension theorem.

Comment: Before continuing I must thank you for thinking this through along with me, I really appreciate it! Yes, the cycle $ab + bc + ca$ has a special role in all this; it is it that distingues the bottle from the torus. Regarding $ag + gd + da$: I'm not actually sure that it is independent of the triangles; but heuristically it seems to me that the linear combinations of triangles only yields triangular or rectangular cycles, and no solitary "lines" or "arcs", if you see what I mean. (Or rather: there are lines that are boundaries of the rectangles, but they come in pairs, like $2(ab+bc+ca)$.)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your last comment. The dimension theorem holds for $Z$-modules, as $Z$ has invariant basis number. My reasoning was: the $18$ triangles $(t_i)$ form a basis for the $Z^{18}$, by definition of the chain complex. Now since the differential $d:Z^{18} \to Z^{27}$ is injective, it preserves linear independence, for a relation $0 = \sum_i a_i d(t_i) = d(\sum_i a_i t_i)$ implies $\sum_i a_i t_i = 0$, whence $a_i = 0$. So the $18$ $1$-cycles $d(t_i)$ are linearly independent.

Comment: I have similar intuition for why I expect $ag+gd+da$ to be an independent cycle, but the issue is that this is not enough to conclude it is independent (hence why I think you'd need to do the matrix reduction).  For the second comment, by "dimension theorem" I mean "a set is a spanning set iff it is an independent set."  For $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, this is unfortunately not the case.  Relevant counterexample: for $\mathbb{Z}^2$, $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and $\{(2,0),(0,1)\}$ are both independent sets, but the latter is not a spanning set.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean, and that is definitely a very important thing that went over my head. So while it seems very plausible that the $18$ triangle cycles plus $ag + gd + da$ are linearly independent, there is no reason to expect them to generate all of the $19$-dimensional space of $1$-cycles! How counterintuitive.

Comment: In [these relevant notes](http://suess.sdf-eu.org/website/lang/de/algtop/notes4.pdf), Examples 4.33, 4.34.1, (see [here](http://suess.sdf-eu.org/website/lang/en/algtop/notes2.pdf) for the triangulation), the author argues that any $1$-chain is homologous to a $1$-chain involving only edges on the perimeter and three additional edges in order to compute the space of $1$-cycles explicitly. But I don't see why this is true; in particular, I don't know how the edge $\langle v_2,v_5 \rangle$ (his notation) can be reduced to that form.

Comment: It seems to me the author is saying the 1-cycles are homologous to 1-cycles in a special form (not any 1-chain).  Are you trying to calculate a basis of 1-cycles or are you trying to compute a basis for homology?  For the latter, use what I was calling a replacement rule --- it is sort of like the game Lights Out.

Comment: In Step 1 of Example 4.33 (this is for the torus, and he argues similarly for the bottle), the author claims that any $1$-chain is homologous to one involving only edges corresponding to edges on the perimeter and $\langle v_1,v_6 \rangle$, $\langle v_1,v_8 \rangle$, $\langle v_7,v_9 \rangle$. I've tried quite a bit but I can't work this out for $\langle v_2,v_5 \rangle$. Anyway, If this is true, then it leads to a nice explicit description of the $1$-cycles and then of $H_1$. My main goal here is to understand this (or any) explicit description of the $1$-cycles.

Comment: If what you want is an explicit description of 1-cycles: (1) take any spanning tree of the graph (2) count the number of edges outside the spanning tree.  Each edge corresponds to an independent cycle by attaching the unique shortest path through the tree between the two endpoints.  Spanning implies there is such a path (otherwise you can add that edge to make the tree bigger).  In your example, the complement of a spanning tree has 19 edges.  These span the 1-cycles because an arbitrary 1-cycle will be cut up by the spanning tree, and anything completely inside the tree is not a cycle or 0.

Comment: Ah, I see! So this has been very well studied in graph theory, and any spanning tree yields a so-called fundamental cycle basis by the procedure you described. This suggests that bases for $1$-cycles are generally quite complicated, and nothing even guarantees that the $18$ triangular cycles may be completed to a basis (in fact, now I very much doubt it). Thank you for all your help!